# Как в git в клон репозитория влить некоторые коммиты из другого (оригинального) репозитория?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

Собственно вопрос:

- Создал на github клон одного проекта.
- Внес в него свои изменения и закоммитил.
- Теперь смотрю в оригинале тоже появились коммиты.

И как перенести коммиты оригинала проекта в свой клон?
Ответ желательно с примером, а не просто ссылка на команды git.

**ЗЫ.**

Вопрос по проге github. В ней есть кнопки:

- revert commit ( create a new commit that reverts the changes  in this commit )
- roll back this commit ( roll back this commit leaving all changes made in this and later commits in your working directory )

За что конкретно они отвечают и чем из них надо воспользоваться, чтобы отменить какой-либо коммит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить оригинальный:

```
git remote add original git:....
```

Создать временную ветку

```
git checkout -b temp
```

Скачать все изменения из ветки master орининального репозитория

```
git pull original master
```

Переключиться обратно на ветку где вы были

```
git checkout -
```

И воспользоваться либо merge, либо cherry pick.

Надеюсь, что общая идея понятна. Если нет - читайте man.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы сделали именно clone (то есть просто `git clone git://some_url`) и теперь хотите получить изменения с сервера, то нужно просто дать команду `git pull`. Она вытянет изменения и попытается смерджить. Правда иногда может не получиться и нужно будет ручками исправить конфликты (если один кусок кода менялся двумя людьми, то иногда и человек не всегда может правильно слить вместе). После исправления конфликта, нужно будет закоммитить.

Comment: Нет. Я просто на гитхабе именно создал клон чужого проекта в свой аккаунт, который уже в последующем скачал (clone) себе на винт и синхронизирую (commit + push) со своим репо на гитхабе.
И вот как раз в оригинальном (чужом) репо происходят изменения. Вот мне и надо взять оттуда изменения (коммиты или что там) и влить их в свой репо.
На самом гитхабе подобного не нашел.

Comment: Это уже называется fork. И если искать так, то находиться очень быстро. Достаточно зайти в справку на github. Конкретно для Вас - [ссылка](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo). Вы сделали первые два шага, а нужно ещё пару. Если не знаете английского, возьмите переводчик (благо онлайн переводчиков много) и аккуратно переведите. Там все подробно написано.